# how to start and stop the scheduledexecutorservice multiple times

Tags: java

I am using ScheduledExecutorService, and after I call it's cancel method on scheduleFuture, I can't schedule a Runnable on it. Calling `scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, INITIAL_DELAY, INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` after `cancel()`, nothing happens. Is there any way to restart the `ScheduledExecutorService` after `cancel()` method is called?

Answer (score 0):

Please review notes on [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and its implementation [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html).

The effect of calling [cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) method is that:

- `subsequent calls to isDone() will always return true. Subsequent

  calls to isCancelled() will always return true if this method

  returned true.`
- `Once the computation has completed, the computation cannot be
  restarted or cancelled.`

Meaning, if a call to `isDone()` returns `true`, whether or not you made a call to `cancel()`, you can't use same instance of your service.

Comment: Please suggest some way by which i can start the service, stop it and restart it again.